# Date Format does not match system format when extracting data from excel on power automate desktop

Tags: windows-10, excel-2016, power-automate-desktop

More than a solution, I'm looking for an explanation on why does this happen.

For context. I'm making a SQL query to an excel file using power automate desktop, this file has dates in dd-mm-yyyy format. What I cannot understand is that those dates appear in mm-dd-yyyy format in my datatable.

[image: Excel data]

[image: Power automate Datatable]

I have checked my regional settings on my windows machine and is set to dd-mm-yyyy, also checked my excel regional settings which is also set to dd-mm-yyyy. Since everything seems in order why does power automate insists to change the data format? Have I missed some obscure setting?

Comment: You said you checked windows and excel, but have you checked your database settings? it doesn't seem to be an issue as the dates are the same, eg the 1st of March (01-03-2024) does not become the 3rd of January (03-01-2024).